# Disabling fingerprint sensor on Oukitel WP6

Tags: fingerprint

I want to completely disable the fingerprint sensor on my Oukitel WP6, rooted, running CAOS (modified Android). That means not just unlocking phone with fingerprint, but completely killing that sensor. Reason being is that many apps use that sensor as a button to perform some action, and it is very difficult not to touch that button accidentally.

I've been reviewing [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/153948/completely-disable-the-fingerprint-sensor) as reference to disable the fpc driver, but for some reason, I can't get access to /sys (permission denied), even though my phone is rooted, and I tried several different terminal apps, giving them full permissions (trying on Termux right now). Also, the instruction there for making this change permanent is very complicated, a bit beyond my capability.

I also tried hardware solution - taping that sensor. It still works unfortunately. I disassembled the phone, but I don't see any obvious point where to unsolder it's connections.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The sensor is not a button.  When a virtual button is placed in the same location, a tap activates the button whereas a long press activates the sensor.  it isn't really an issue. On normal phones, you can disable biometry sensors/  Cant you do that here ?

Comment: @RohitGupta - I can't seem to disable it. I already disabled fingerprint as unlock mechanism in the settings, but there is no setting to disable that sensor entirely.

Comment: Then you have weird-rooted software.  This functionality exists on normal phones.  Try messaging the author of your replacement OS.

Comment: @RohitGupta But as far as I've searched, even on regular Android OS, there is no way to disable the sensor in the settings. It can be disabled for biometrics, but not as a button. And like I wrote, I want to disable it entirely, make phone unaware of it regardless of the context.

Comment: Well, I am dreaming then.  On my Samsung Note 20, it is not a button.  It is shaded in and responds only if biometrics is enabled.

Comment: @RohitGupta And if you disable it there, it doesn't do anything when you are in other apps, like browser, Waze? No action is performed when you tap or hold your finger on that sensor in these apps?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @RohitGupta I see... Well, my OS is no longer developed, so there is nothing I can do there. Going to need a different solution. I do need to use this specific OS.